Facing Cors and 401 error working on this code
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/meetings`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            mode: 'no-cors',
            withCredentials: false,
            credentials: 'include'
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching meetings:', error);
            });

Header file doesn't send the token properly to the server and how do fix those errors in frontend code
